# Spring MVC doesn't serve static files after form submission

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

The controller of my Spring MVC web application listens:

- to `"/admin"` to return the admin page,
- to `"/admin/change"` which is called when the form on the admin page is submitted. Then the controller again returns the admin page.

---

Here's my **AdminController.java**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin") 
public class AdminController {      

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String admin(Map<String, Object> model, Principal principal) {

        return "admin"; //returns admin.jsp
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/change", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changeClient(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> form,
            Map<String, Object> model, Principal principal) {

        model.put("message", "Changed to " + form.getFirst("client"));
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

---

Here's an excerpt from my **admin.jsp**:

```
<form action="/admin/change" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group has-success">
        <label class="control-label">Select the client</label>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input class="radio" name="client" type="radio" value="1">
                <span>Melik</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input class="radio" name="client" type="radio" value="2">
                <span>Memmed</span>
            </label>
            <input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Switch</button>
            <c:if test="${message != null}">
                <span class="has-success"><c:out value="${message}"/></span>
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I access `/admin`, a beautiful admin.jsp is served, however, when I submit a form on this page and then return admin.jsp, this time static files are not being served with admin.jsp.

This is how I reference the static files in my jsp (I'm guessing here might be a problem but I wasn't able to fix it):

```
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/vendor.css">
```

I also tried the following variation with `<c:url>` tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Admin Panel </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<c:url value="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/vendor.css"/>">
    <!-- Theme initialization -->
    <script>
        var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
            {};
        var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
        if (themeName)
        {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="<c:url value="/css/app-' + themeName + '.css"/>">');
        }
        else
        {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="<c:url value="/css/app.css"/>">');
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Also after form submission, Chrome shows the following error on the returned admin page:

```
    Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/admin/css/app.css'
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type,
and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

---

Here's an excerpt from my **dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

---

And here's my **project structure**:

```
src:
--main:
----java
----resources:
------app.properties
----webapp:
------css
------js
------WEB-INF:
--------dispatcher-servlet.xml
--------web.xml
--------pages:
----------admin.jsp
```

---

So, why my admin.jsp is returned without static files after form submission?

Comment: Are you running in a servlet context?  Or are you running on the ROOT servlet context?  You might need to use the <c:url> tag for your urls.  More information:  https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-curl-core-tag/

Comment: I'm running on the ROOT

Comment: @hooknc, I've added `<c:url>` tags in every js and css link, but result is the same. Also please see edit on the question.

Comment: As the message shows, the problem is with app.css. You haven't told us how you include *that* css file. My bet is that you're using a relative path instead of an absolute one, since it tries loading `/admin/css/app.css` rather than `/css/app.css`, and /admin is precisely the "directory" of your /admin/change url.

Comment: check your browser web-tools in Network tab, check if the request for the resources are the same

Comment: @JBNizet, I have included it now. Please check the update.